# Empty answer in failed review audit

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I just failed a review audit in the low quality queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4723971

The answer here shows as completely empty, but of course it was not when I reviewed the question - So this looks like a bug to me. Or is there any reason why this should show an empty answer here? I can't learn much from this.

Comment: The answer was deleted as SPAM. Since you don't have 10k rep, you can't see it now.

Comment: You did, however, see that answer during the review, so you did think `HyperImageView is a an alternative for UIImageView which renders images 30 times faster than UIImageView while uses 10 times less RAM [spam link omitted]` looked *good*. Please, pay attention while reviewing, otherwise you become part of the problem, not of the solution.

Comment: You might have even seen something like: _this was marked as spam.. review this carefully.._ during the review in question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The question was about asking some memory preservation and runtime speed. So it seemed to me to be not overly bad to recommend a toolkit which might be a better fit. However, I didn't check the link and I am also not familiar with the whole toolkit, so it seems a made a mistake. My bad, I know, but mistakes happen. I think this was the second review failure I every had, so I don't feel like I am part of the problem.

Comment: @devnull Uh, oh, thanks for the hint, I obviously didn't read that.

Comment: Still, I consider the current behaviour a bug. I can see why it is happening now, but it is super-strange: The failed review told me I should review the failed audit very carefully (which I would have) and then is shows me: nothing. This is not helpful at all. _At least_ it should show a message that this was spam and I am therefore unable to see it.

Comment: @dirkk, answers only recommending a toolkit, spam or not, is not what we expect from answers on Stack Overflow. We even close questions asking for recommendations in order to prevent such answers.

Comment: I do agree that deleted answers should still be shown on failing an audit so that we can review where we went wrong

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I agree. As I said, I made a mistake. However, this was neither my question here nor did I argue that I was wrongfully failed.

Answer (score 17):

I agree. [Deleted posts should be made visible to reviewers via the review link, no matter their reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed). It's the only way that you'll be able to see what you did wrong in an audit or a moderator-imposed ban.

In this case, it was a post that was deleted as spam:

[image: Post under review]

which might not be obvious at first glance from that post, but that user had posted the same answer advertising their for-pay component on 11 older questions. People finally got fed up and flagged this as spam, with the post being deleted for that reason.

Comment: Happened to me too. I found my review audit a border-line case and thought a few seconds about it and was surprised. When I tried to reread the audit, nothing was shown. An opportunity to learn missed.

Comment: Could you show me this review audit? http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5467467

Comment: @nalply - It was an answer that was flagged as spam (which it shouldn't have been, and I've cleared that flag) and deleted from review, without a moderator's intervention: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24601396/19679 . It was just someone describing a plugin that could be used, and should not have been an audit case. Now that I've removed the bad spam flag on it, it shouldn't appear again.