# Is the "STOP! Look and Listen" broken?

Tags: bug, review-queues, deleted-answers

I was reviewing an answer deletion request (it was at -1) and received a "STOP! Look and Listen." audit. But the audit page didn't show the answer I was reviewing, so there's no way to see what I did wrong.

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647417/admob-plugins-compatible-with-phonegap-3-4/25760180#25760180) (shows as deleted). I can see the question (very faded out):

[image]

The text even says to "look it over closely", but there's nothing to see.

Comment: Technically, it's by design. When you pass or fail an audit, it shows the post _how it really looks_, which just happens to be deleted. I bet if you had 10k, the text would be shown.

Comment: This is a bit off - you're *supposed* to be able to see the post *that you reviewed*, even if it is deleted - in this case you can't, probably because the *question* was also deleted - which *probably* should've made it ineligible for an audit in the first place.

Comment: The text isn't even shown to 10K users, because it was marked as spam.

Comment: +1 for failing an audit so you could report this bug

Comment: Even worse, the answer that was deleted isn't obvious spam. It's *possible* that it was being inappropriately posted by the user as an answer to many questions, but if so, the other answers are no longer visible on the user's profile, so it's not apparent to an auditor.

Comment: The question asked *"Does anyone know of a working plugin for displaying Ads in a PhoneGap application?"* and that's what that user answered by linking to his open source project mentioning he's a contributor. I wouldn't use it an as exemplary audit post of this kind as well. Btw., [the story continues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26106753/960757)... Now with 2 *spam (?) posts*.

Comment: @gunr2171 It's implausible that it was intentionally designed to be this crappy ... show us the spec where it says "Tell the user to look at a blank answer".

Comment: @JimBalter: That's a silly thing to say; gunr obviously didn't mean to suggest that such wording would be in any specification. However, it's completely plausible that a defect/omission in the specification leaves this condition to be strictly compliant, even though it's undesirable. Of course it's more likely that no such specification actually exists :P

Comment: No, it wasn't silly, it was wise; your silly response misses my point while stating it yourself.

Comment: @gunr2171: When I reviewed the answer I could see its text, so unless it was deleted during the review, it's not showing me what I did wrong.

Comment: @Shog9: And the question couldn't be closed while I was reviewing, right? Isn't the point of an audit that you take a question/answer that's already closed and show it to the user?

Comment: If you've gone to look at the answer (judging low quality of late posts involves checking they aren't just repeating an answer that was posted much earlier, which the review screen shows) and the answer is then deleted, the fact that you went to the question page isn't recorded, though you know there's nothing left to do.

Answer (score 4):

So I guess this will be fixed in 6-8 weeks? Hello.

[Allow all reviewers to see deleted posts they reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed)

[Empty answer in failed review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253582/empty-answer-in-failed-review-audit)