# Got a review ban due to an unfair/wrong audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

So, a couple of weeks ago I got a serious ban. Took 7 days off, relaxed, and reviewed very carefully ever since. 
Now I got this audit - https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6351639

The post in question looked like this before it was deleted:

[image: screenshot]

This might have been a wrong answer, but it was an answer nevertheless. Not a comment, not a link only answer, not anything else that due to which we remove low quality posts. I've read numerous posts here on meta saying that those should be downvoted and not removed. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029) for example:

> If the above doesn’t apply, choose Looks OK. This is the correct choice for answers that are just wrong.

I'd appreciate if this audit could be reverted.

EDIT: While rereading this knowing that it was deleted as spam I definitely justify that decision, I still argue that this is an unfair audit, as the answer looks perfectly valid other than that little link at the end. It's very hard to decide that this is spam while looking at it from the review queue without knowing any back story or a direction or what type of flag was raised. A low quality flag is wrong in that case anyway.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the answer? It has been deleted and only 10k users (and you, the reviewer) can see it.

Comment: @ProgramFOX the reviewer can't see the answer as well... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253582/empty-answer-in-failed-review-audit

Comment: Oh, I thought you could see it when you go back to the review. If not, can a 10k user provide a screenshot please?

Comment: I added a copy of the post. It was deleted as spam.

Comment: Why the link? That looks spammish to me.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't post the link. This is a post about a review audit in which the answer with the link was given. While rereading this *knowing* that it was deleted as spam I justify that decision, I still argue that this is an unfair audit, as the answer looks perfectly valid other than that little link at the end.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the OP here is the reviewer. Not the answerer.

Comment: The answerer is currently suspended for "posting promotional content".

Comment: This post *is* spam. The user posted five answers in a row all linking to that site with "barely an answer" attached to each of them. I can only refer you to the Meta SE request linked above. Spam posts are not always as obvious because sometimes they have backstory that isn't visible, like in this case.

Comment: Ah, got it. I withdraw my erroneous comments.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is while the spam is not obvious, the post **was** spam. Don't expect every review post to be obvious. It is up to you, the reviewer, to check the validity of the link etc.

As a minimum you should have (attempted) to edit the link out of the post, and as that wouldn't have been possible as the post was already deleted the likelihood that the item was a review audit that you needed to downvote/flag would have been very high.

You say a *low quality* flag was wrong anyway, but that doesn't mean that low quality was all you should look out for. In the *First Posts* queue you should look out for anything and everything, and that applies to all queues whether or not the original flag was right or wrong.

Hopefully you have learnt for next time. This is the point of review audits when all said and done!