# Low Quality posts review : empty answer

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

While reviewing low quality posts, I got the "Stop, pay attention" message. After clicking "I understand", I was not directed to another question (because failing a review will lock review capabilities for 2 days).

When that happens, clicking on the review link again will show you the following message :

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see : [link to reviewed element]

Clicking on [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7399956) sends me back to an empty answer :

[image: Empty question]

Is this normal ? Was the answer deleted ? I've read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed) from last year about showing deleted posts to reviewers but it doesn't look like it's being acted upon.
If someone with moderator privileges can post the original answer as a part of their answer, I'd be greatful, since I still don't understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Can you post the link to the review?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question to add the link.

Comment: That post was deleted as spam. It is perhaps not the best audit post, however. There was a link to a $10 product in the post; most likely the OP did nothing but post links to that product in answers.

Comment: I see, thanks. I've read similar remarks from other reviewers who got tricked by the same type of answer while trying to make sure I wasn't posting a duplicate question. I suppose I'll have to pay extra attention to those answers containing a link and actually follow the link every time to check on its content. I do try to pay attention to every single post I review, so I think that if this tricked me, it's perhaps not such a bad idea to leave it as audit post, after all, I did learn something out of this.

Comment: possibly related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253582/empty-answer-in-failed-review-audit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, this was the answer:

[image: Example from review]

This was flagged as spam, and I removed it as such, because the point of the answer was to promote the product in the second link. If you went through that link, you would see that this was a commercial product being sold by the person who posted the answer. Without disclosure, this was astroturfing at best.

You didn't have this context, but they were doing this on multiple unrelated questions as well. However, you didn't need to see those to be suspicious of a new answer like this promoting a commercial product.

To the core problem of not being able to see things you've reviewed that were deleted, I'll once again point to [my feature request here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed). Reviewers should be able to see these so that they can figure out what might have gone wrong with their review.

Comment: Thanks for providing context, I now know exactly what to watch out for. I upvoted your request the first time I saw it (is there anything else I can do ?), and will mark this question as duplicate, I did search for dupes but missed the one pointed out by Kevin B, sorry about that.